# div size inconsistent between chrome and firefox

Tags: css, html

I'm running into an interesting issue in the way a DIV with text occupies space in Firefox and Chrome. I have a bar chart that expands horizontally, each bar is made of a vertical bar and a title underneath.

```
<div class="verticalChart">
  <div class="singleBar">
    <div class="bar"><!-- contents set by javascript, equal size for all bars--></div>
    <div class="title">What is a fraction</div>
  </div>
  <div class="singleBar">
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="title">Unit Fractions on Number Line</div>
  </div>
[...] <!-- more bars -->
</div>
```

I have the following CSS applied to the titles below each of the bars to make sure that their bottom is at the same y coordinate. I allow the text to occupy at most 3 lines after which it overflows beyond the visible box:

```
.verticalChart .singleBar .title {
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 1.0em;
  min-height: 3.0em;
  max-height: 3.0em;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

I basically need the height of the title block to be always the same, or the bars will be misaligned. What's interesting is that this seems to work just fine in Firefox:

[image: firefox]

but is a no-go on Chrome:

[image: chrome]

My suspicion, based on fiddling with the numbers, is that min-height in Firefox acts differently from min-height in Chrome:

- In Firefox reducing min-height below 3em will remove the extra lines from the title divs that don't need it, mis-aligning the bars above them.
- In Chrome changing min-height only serves to push the scroll-bar below closer or furtheraway. The div with the bar + title do not move with respect to each other in any way.

What exactly is going on here? Am I perhaps achieving the "min-height" effect of the title block the wrong way? Is there a more cross-browser-friendly approach?

Many thanks!

Edit:

JSFiddle as per popular demand: http://jsfiddle.net/YJHrY/4/

Comment: What version of Firefox & what version of Chrome?

Comment: Firefox 18.0.2 from the default Canonical repo and Chrome Version 24.0.1312.69 from the same place.

Comment: Can you fiddle your code?

Comment: @Cadence96: Sure thing! http://jsfiddle.net/YJHrY/4/ Make sure to move the right pane to the left enough so that the bars get wide enough for this issue to reproduce on Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I supposed, you are using a display property with a value of inline-block, those by default are aligned to bottom.
http://jsfiddle.net/YJHrY/5/

Add a vertical-align: top to your .verticalChart .singleBar

```
.verticalChart .singleBar {
    /* FrontRow Edits */
    width: 4.4%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0 1% 0% 1%;
    float: none;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: That seems to do the trick, thanks a lot. Do you happen to know why Firefox didn't appear to display that issue?

Comment: Nope, but Webkit browsers are more consistent about following the rules, that must be the reason.

Comment: Sounds good, thanks! I'll just have to keep in mind that it's better to be specific about what alignment I need in situations where it's important, rather than leaving it up to the browser.

Comment: You just need to be specific about the alignment when you deal with inline/inline-block related elements.